# MongoDB Aggregation: calculation for every unique/distinct value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I got this data set from collection

```
{
    item: 124001
    price: 6
},
{
   item: 124001
   price: 6
},
{
   item: 124121
   price: 16
},
{
    item: 124121
    price: 13
},
{
   item:n
   price: x
}
```

from code:

```
let INDX = [xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx, ..n]
auctions.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { item: { $in: INDX }}
    }
```

The problem is right after it, in the $group stage. For example I'd like to receive $min, $max or $avg 'price' for every unique/distinct item.

When I'm trying to use:

```
{
    $group: {
        min_1: { $min: "$price",}
    }
}
```

I receive just $min from all data,

```
[ { _id: 0, min_1: 0 } ]
```

but I need something like:

```
{ _id: 124119, min_1: 66500 },
{ _id: 124437, min_1: 26398 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is a simple answer:

Just don't forget about _id field and use it, at $group stage, just like:

```
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$item",
            min_1: {
                $min: '$price',
            }
        }
    }
```